# What's the difference between these two ways to get the canvas object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

```
canvas = $('#canvasID');

canvas = document.getElementById('canvasID');
```

What's the difference? why can't I use `canvas.offset()` when i get the canvas object by the second way?

Comment: The second line returns a CANVAS element, the first line returns a jQuery object which contains that same CANVAS element as its `'0'` property. Note that `document.getElementById('x') === $('#x')[0]`

Comment: @user915717 Edited your question. It's equally valid in HTML4, too, supposing you have an object with `id="canvasID"`

Answer (score 6):

`$('#canvasID')` uses jQuery to fetch the element.

`document.getElementById('canvasID');` uses the browsers native implementation to fetch an element by it's ID.

The implementation of `$("#canvasID")` differs among browsers, but i suspect that it actually uses `document.getElementByID()` under the hood on all modern browsers.

The reason why you can't use `offset` with the second method is because it's a method on the jQuery object (which is returned from `$('#canvasID');`).

Answer (score 0):

The [`.offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) method is a jQuery method. The `$()` function returns an array of jQuery wrapped objects matching the selector. So you can invoke jQuery methods on them. `document.getElementById('canvasID');` returns the native DOM element which doesn't have such method defined.

Answer (score 0):

[`offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) is a jQuery method and can be applied to jQuery objects as returned by the `$` (or `jQuery`) function. To get a raw canvas object, access the elements of this object, with `$('#canvasID')[0]`.

`document.getElementById` returns the raw object. To get a jQuery object from a raw HTML object, call `$` with it.

In summary:

```
var jquery_canvas = $('#canvas');
var raw_canvas = jquery_canvas[0];
var jquery_canvas_again = $(raw_canvas);

var context = raw_canvas.getContext('2d');
// NOT: jquery_canvas.getContext(), as getContext is only defined on raw object

var offset = raw_canvas.offset();
// NOT: raw_canvas.offset(), as offset is only defined on a jQuery object
```

Answer (score 0):

with the first way, you're getting an jquery-object representing that element - and that jquery-object has an `offset()`-method.
with `getElementById()` you're getting a "plain" javascrip-object, with doesn't know this method.

Answer (score 0):

`$('#canvasID')` uses jQuery

`document.getElementByID('canvasID')` uses the browsers native implementation, basically raw JavaScript.

You cannot use the `.offset()` method because you're trying to use it on a non jQuery object.